# SELECT Using Email Addresses

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using PHP with PDO

Trying to retrieve records from a table using the email as a key. When the email is given directly in the sql statement, it works fine,

But when I am sending the email in a field "$bio_email", it does not work. The email field from the table is type "varchar"

I have tried several options but neither one works. The error that the system is returning is in the right hand side of the sql statement

this is my code

```
$bio_email      = $applicantinfo->user_email; // email from a table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_files_upload WHERE ";
$sql .= " email = 'applicant1@live.ca' "; // THIS WORKS FINE
//$sql .= " email = 'danilo.gonzalez@parkinson.ca' "; // THIS WORKS FINE
//$sql .= " email = $bio_email "; // DOES NOT WORK  ... syntax to use near '@live.ca' at line 1
//$sql .= " email = {$bio_email} "; // DOES NOT WORK  ... syntax to use near '@live.ca' at line 1
//$sql .= " email = &#39;{$bio_email}&#39; "; // DOES NOT WORK ... syntax to use near ''applicant1@live.ca'' at line 1
//$sql .= " email = &#39;$bio_email&#39; "; // DOES NOT WORK ... syntax to use near ''applicant1@live.ca'' at line 1

$biosketchs = Tb_Files_Upload::find_by_sql($sql);
```

Also in the same table I have a field "dateReceived". I would like to have the records that are 2.5 years old. Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try

```
$sql .= " email = '$bio_email' ";
```

for the dateReceived, just DATE_SUB for month, and for year inside.

```
dateReceived >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

or let's not be stupid and use 18 months directly

```
$sql.= " AND dateReceived >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)";
```

Comment: Thank you, this works fine for the email. For the date range I tried this:     $sql .= " dateReceived >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR"; But it selects everything and I need to select records from the previous 2.5 years

Comment: @Danilo sorry, missed the dateReceived part. Edited.